# Android: Reduce BackStack memory usage

Tags: android, performance

I'm creating an app that takes the user through a fairly long, linear, process of data capturing. Each activity leads to a new one for a new topic for which the data needs to be entered. The problem is that some of the activities have many or large bitmaps, or many imageButtons. When the user goes to the next activity, the current one is placed one the backstack and the memory does not get cleaned up.

I am considering calling 'finish()' when the user goes to the next activity and then overriding 'onBackPressed()' to recreate the previous activity if the user needs to go back and change a value there. Is there any better suggestions than to do this?

Comment: How are you using bitmap inside your activities? Post your code please

Comment: you could store the bitmaps in a "soft" cache, remove hard references in onStop and try to load them from the cache in onStart

Comment: @an_droid_dev Many of the images are part of the layout, so part of ImageViews or Buttons in the layout xml files. Others are photos taken by the user during the use of the app.

Comment: @lelloman thanks for the tip! I'm not sure what a soft-cache is, but I'll go have a readup on it. Would this help https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/cache-bitmap.html ?

Comment: well i might have made that word up :D anyway yes that link helps, but i would suggest you to just use a library (for example Picasso) to load the images into the imageviews in on start, and then in on stop set all of them to null so that they can be released if needed

Comment: @lelloman haha awesome! thanks, I will definitely take a look!

Comment: He probably meant WeakReference. It doesn't really help if the activity holding it never dies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you consider is certainly on the right track.

My only addition to that (recreating the activities when you need to go back to them) is that you don't necessarily need many activities.

From what I understand you need many layouts, each with its relevant resources. What I'd do is:

- create your `Stage` data class, holing a layout, bitmap id's, etc
- create a `List<Stage>` with the full story
- create one activity that knows how to display a stage from the list, and traverse to other stages. Here you can override the back button to act as stage traversal.

Check out [The Transitions Framework](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/overview.html) to see how you can animate views when traversing between the above stages. If you use the same id for at least some of your views - they will move around independently, while other views will fade out or in.

Comment: Thanks auval! That sounds like a pretty cool idea. But, what would be the advantage of doing this as opposed to just re-creating the activities? Sorry if its a silly question, I'm still very new to this.

Comment: Creating many Activities is just a lot of repetitive work and it's cumbersome. And just modifying layouts allows you to animate parts of the layout using layout transitions (not just animate the whole screen, like in Activity). There are more advantages.

Comment: Unfortunately, I already have created all the activities. I think I'll try and override onBackPressed() and when I have time I'll try this implementation - it sounds really cool.

Comment: Cool. It may be possible to reuse the layout files you already created for the activities.